# Вызов функции из другой функции. Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно вызвать функцию, но есть одно "но"...
Вот код:

```
def accountMenu():
   def menu():
      'какой либо код'
```

Как мне вызвать функцию menu(), не вызывая её из функции accountMenu()?
Чтобы вы могли понять о чём речь, то попробую донести это вот так:
Я предполагал что может сработает вот это `accountMenu.menu()`, но нет.
Я мог бы просто сделать вот так:

```
def accountMenu():
   def menu():
      'какой либо код'
    menu()
   'другой код который вызывать повторно нельзя'
```

Но я не могу так сделать, потому что тогда это вызывет сбой, т.к. в `accountMenu()` есть другой код, который повторно вызывать нельзя. Вообщем, это трудно обьяснить. Надеюсь вы поймёте, и поможете мне.

Comment: почему функция `menu` должна быть обязательно вложенной в `accountMenu`? Что мешает вынести ее наружу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант сделать `accountMenu` классом, и внутри него объявить функцию `menu`, но все равно это неправильно с точки зрения логики, и даже Python выдаст тебе предупреждение

```
class AccountMenu:
    def menu():
        return 'какой либо код'


print(AccountMenu.menu())
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Нужно вынести функцию `menu()` за пределы `accountMenu()`. Какой смысл определять её внутри, если требуется вызвать её снаружи?!